# How to utilise and end loop appropriately

Tags: python, python-3.x

context, i am a beginner in coding, barely halfway into my semester for my coding module and just decided to try out a coding question. here is the question, and my code attempt

if it's possible to separate the digits with either a plus or minus sign to get the final expression to equal zero.

For example: if num is 35132 then it's possible to separate the digits the following way, 3 - 5 + 1 + 3 - 2, and this expression equals zero. Your program should return a string of the signs you used. if impossible to equate to zero, return "no solution"

```
import random

number = input ("input the number to be ran through the program: ")
zero = "0"

a = number + zero
a = str(a)
length = len(a) - 1

while True:
    plusminus = "+-"
    op = random.choices(plusminus, k= length)
    operations = "".join(op)

    eqn = ''.join(map(''.join, zip(a, operations)))
    eqn = eqn[0:-1]
    ans = eval(eqn)
    
    if ans == 0:
        print(operations[:-1])
        break
```

i am unable to get my loop to end with "no solution" if there is no solution, how do i end the loop if there is no solution, and print out the string?
also, this code feels "unclean" to me, with the zero variable added so tat my equation(eqn) ends with a number instead of +/-, and "while true" feels out of place, but i needed it to loop the random function. how would you guys code this? thanks!

i have tried adding print at the end of code, but when there is a solution, it will print "-++-" "no soln", i have tried using looping at ans ==0, and compiling the possibilities of loops into a list, but it ended up as a an infinite loop of list rather than a list of infinite strings(is it even possible?).

Comment: ok, but your code does nothing of this. You just have numbers represented as string for some reason, and then some other reason you use `eval`, which you should absolutely avoid

Comment: Why would you use random instead of doing an exhaustive search?

Comment: See the combinatoric operators in https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Comment: Instead of randomly choosing "+" or "-", try iterating over all possibilities. This will probably involve a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop. If all possibilities have been checked and no solution is found, then you can return `no solution`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Actually, random could be beneficial. If you have many digits, exhaustive search might take a long time to find a solution whereas random might find one with relatively few attempts. So one could try let's say 1000 random attempts before starting an exhaustive search. (Or of course you could just write a DP solution, but that's maybe not for beginners.)

Comment: @Elerium115 That doesn't sound like you've read the code...

Answer (score 0):

Think I resolved it now:

```
import random

def find_zero_equation(number, max_attempts=1000):
    length = len(number)
    plusminus = "+-"

    for _ in range(max_attempts):
        op = random.choices(plusminus, k=length-1)
        operations = "".join(op)

        # Construct the expression
        expr = ''.join(map(''.join, zip(number, operations))) + number[-1]

        # Evaluate the expression
        try:
            ans = eval(expr)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            continue  # Skip if there's a division by zero

        if ans == 0:
            print(operations)
            return

    print("no solution")

number = input("Input the number to be run through the program: ")
find_zero_equation(number)
```

Comment: The OP only needs to use a TTL if their loop is infinite, and the design that uses an infinite loop is itself suboptimal for their use case; the number of possible operator sets is short enough -- for fairly small numbers of digits -- that they can do an exhaustive search.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 'no solution' if the loop gets timed out, you can give a condional statement like if the length of the input is more than 400, return no solution

```
import random as rd

opns = 'add', 'subtract'
number = input ("input the number to be ran through the program: ")
r = 0
if len(number) > 400:
    print('no solution')

else:
    #iterate thru the input string
    for x in number:
    
        #random choice between add or subtract
        choice = rd.choices(opns)

        #if the random choice is add, then add
        if choice == ['add']:
            r = r + int(x)
    
        #if the random choice is subtract, subtract
        else:
            r = r - int(x)

    print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

First a note about `eval`: It can run arbitrary code, so it's ok to use it like that when you enter numbers yourself, but never use it to evaluate input from sources you can't trust, like your friend who'd find it hilarious if you deleted all your files or sent a love-email to your secret crush.

### Solution 1: Minimal fix

Replace the random search

```
while True:
    plusminus = "+-"
    op = random.choices(plusminus, k= length)
    ...
```

with an exhaustive search:

```
plusminus = "+-"
for op in itertools.product(plusminus, repeat= length):
    ...
```

And add this at the end, which prints if there was no `break`:

```
else:
    print("no solution")
```

### Solution 2: Template version

Another way to build the candidates, which I find much simpler/cleaner:

```
import itertools

number = '35132'

n = len(number)
k = n - 1
template = [None] * (n+k)
template[::2] = number
for ops in itertools.product('+-', repeat=k):
    template[1::2] = ops
    if not eval(''.join(template)):
        print(''.join(ops))
        break
else:
    print('no solution')
```

### Solution 3: Dynamic programming

This is an efficient but somewhat advanced technique, though a fairly simple case here. Build a dictionary mapping values to operator strings that produced those values:

```py
number = '35132'

d = {int(number[0]): ''}
for digit in number[1:]:
    digit = int(digit)
    new = {}
    for val, ops in d.items():
        new[val + digit] = ops + '+'
        new[val - digit] = ops + '-'
    d = new
print(d.get(0, 'no solution'))
```

Here's what the dictionary looks like at the end:

```
{14: '++++',
 10: '+++-',
 8: '+-+-',
 4: '-+++',
 12: '+-++',
 6: '+--+',
 2: '--++',
 0: '-++-',
 -2: '--+-',
 -6: '-+--',
 -4: '---+',
 -8: '----'}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZZBNCoMwEIX3OcXsxuAPWikUwZOIixajDWgiGi2leJJu3LR36lm6aX7sylnN5H3zmLznu7-rqxTr-ppUHZ4-XzF1FzZADpgek_SAhFR6eHChPCcVcUkzQFxILQeoeMMVcAGbmGRlRkCXE3Iwi7an9lmwm7Fb7GAM5nMbgOxH41FFXLFu9Kiz2PhCI-A7w1IvG9gH9HEHhTsodJD5goZIP9hzooYpLw4AhYRRtpPiUiClLoItiX8iPw)